# Extending base class while preserving original methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm having some issue creating an extended parser of another class.
Here is a schematic version of what I have

```
#include <iostream>

class HeaderType{
public:
  HeaderType(){ this->value1 = 0; }
  double getValue1(){return this->value1;}
  void setValue1(double v){ this->value1 = v; }
protected:
  double value1;
};

class Parser{
public:
  Parser() { this->header = new HeaderType(); }
  virtual ~Parser() {};

  virtual void Parse(){ this->header->setValue1(10); }
  HeaderType* getHeader(){return this->header;}

protected:
  HeaderType* header;
};

class ExtendedHeaderType : public HeaderType{
public:
  ExtendedHeaderType(){ this->value2 = 0; }
  double getValue2(){return this->value2;}
  void setValue2(double v){ this->value2 = v; }
protected:
  double value2;
};

class ExtendedParser : public Parser{
public:
  ExtendedParser() : Parser() { this->header = new ExtendedHeaderType(); }
  virtual ~ExtendedParser(){ delete this->header; }
  ExtendedHeaderType* getHeader(){return this->header;} 
  virtual void Parse(){ Parser::Parse(); this->header->setValue2(20); }
protected:
  ExtendedHeaderType* header;
};

int main()
{
  ExtendedParser* parser = new ExtendedParser();
  parser->Parse();
  ExtendedHeaderType* header = parser->getHeader();
  double value = header->getValue1();  

  std::cerr << "Value: " << value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I do that, getValue1() always return 0, I don't really understand why.
When I do parser->Parse(), it should call Parser::Parse(), which set the value1 to 10, and when I do getValue1(), then it should return 10, not 0.
I don't really understand why this is happening.

Thank you.

**Edit:** When I use this code and call header->getValue1() in the main it returns 0, however calling header->getValue2() returns 20 (as expected).

**Edit 2:** Actually I think what I'm trying to do is not possible (or at least not in a clean way). I think instead I will have to create a HeaderType, and an ExtendedHeaderType but that is not a derived class of HeaderType, and create a instance of each in the ExtendedParser.
IMO it would be better to be able to 'extend' a class, but I think in term of memory it's difficult, because the base class is allocated first, then the derived class, but then it's difficult for a derived class to modify the data type of the base class, as it will require a different amount of memory.

Comment: You're not initializing `value1` and `value2` in your constructors.

Comment: Both ExtendedParser and Parser define a member with the same name  'header'. You don't have to redefine it in ExtendedParser

Comment: In your example code you never set `value1` so it's unclear what non-zero value it should be.

Comment: Whats with all of the pointers?  There does not seem to be a reason in the example code to need pointers.

Comment: Ok, so I modified the code to be a bit more realistic (but I cannot put the original code as it's way too big).
Why is this a problem to use pointers ?

Comment: If I don't put 'header' with an ExtendedHeaderType in the ExtendedParser, then I cannot set value2 in ExtendedParser::Parse(). I get an error message saying HeaderType doesn't have a value2 member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance cannot redefine a field to change its type - so what your code does, essentially, is create a class ExtendedParser, with two fields:

1. Parser::header of type HeaderType*
2. ExtendedParser::header of type ExtendedHeaderType*

The reason you are getting 0 in value1, is because Parse in ExtendedParser calls Parse on the base class which updates value1 of Parser::header. Then it updates value2 in ExtendedParser::header.

Then you call getHeader which returns ExtendedParser::header, and indeed, its value1 field was never touched so you get 0.

There are several ways to achieve what I think you want to do. One would be not to redefine header in ExtendedParser, but you’ll have to downcast header to ExtendedHeaderType in ExtendedParser::Parse. Another way would be to use composition instead of inheritance (see the [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern), both for Parser and HeaderType.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's indeed what I ended using (composition). But I'm not really familiar with decorator design pattern, so I will have a look at it. Thanks again :)